# Solr 3.3.0 - Increase field weight in search - boost field priority

Tags: solr, field, edismax

I'm indexing with solr 3.3.0 these docs:

```
<book id="bk101">
        <keywords>----</keywords>
        <title>----</title>
        <owner>----</owner>
        <artist>abcde</artist>
    </book>
    <book id="bk102">
        <keywords>----</keywords>
        <title>----</title>
        <owner>abcde</owner>
        <artist>----</artist>
    </book>
    <book id="bk103">
        <keywords>----</keywords>
        <title>----</title>
        <owner>----</owner>
        <artist>abc</artist>
    </book>
    <book id="bk104">
        <keywords>----</keywords>
        <title>----</title>
        <owner>abc</owner>
        <artist>----</artist>
    </book>
    <book id="bk105">
        <keywords>abcde</keywords>
        <title>----</title>
        <owner>----</owner>
        <artist>----</artist>
    </book>
    <book id="bk106">
        <keywords>abc</keywords>
        <title>----</title>
        <owner>----</owner>
        <artist>----</artist>
    </book>
    <book id="bk107">
        <keywords>----</keywords>
        <title>abcde</title>
        <owner>----</owner>
        <artist>----</artist>
    </book>
    <book id="bk108">
        <keywords>----</keywords>
        <title>abc</title>
        <owner>----</owner>
        <artist>----</artist>
    </book>
```

Schema.xml

```
<types>
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="false">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" splitOnNumerics="0" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true" />
        <filter class="solr.ISOLatin1AccentFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15" side="front" />
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15" side="back" />
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="text_original" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="false">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="uuid" class="solr.UUIDField" indexed="true" />
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" />
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.FloatField" omitNorms="true" />
    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.DateField" />
</types>

<fields>
    <field name="id" type="uuid" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NEW" />
    <field name="book_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="keywords" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="keywords_ex" type="text_original" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="title_ex" type="text_original" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="owner" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="owner_ex" type="text_original" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="artist" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="artist_ex" type="text_original" indexed="true" stored="true" />

    <copyField source="title" dest="title_ex" />
    <copyField source="keywords" dest="keywords_ex" />
    <copyField source="owner" dest="owner_ex" />
    <copyField source="artist" dest="artist_ex" />

</fields>
```

As you can see if I search for 'abc' solr returns all docs (I'm using solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory for indexing); my achievement is to have as result documents sorted using this logic:

1. title_ex
2. title
3. keywords_ex
4. keywords
5. owner_ex
6. artist_ex
7. owner
8. artist

I tryed "^" lucene sintax and dismax but the response list isn't the one I supposed.

`http://localhost:8080/solr33a/core0/select?q=abc&defType=edismax&qf=title_ex^10%20title^8.0%20keywords_ex^6%20keywords^5.5%20owner_ex^1.2%20artist_ex^0.8%20owner^0.5%20artist^0.2&fl=*,score

Result:

```
<doc>
            <float name="score">2.3862944</float>
            <str name="artist">----</str>
            <str name="artist_ex">----</str>
            <str name="book_id">bk108</str>
            <str name="id">2cc5d478-6901-4777-abc9-680fd959ef90</str>
            <str name="keywords">----</str>
            <str name="keywords_ex">----</str>
            <str name="owner">----</str>
            <str name="owner_ex">----</str>
            <str name="title">abc</str>
            <str name="title_ex">abc</str>
        </doc>
        <doc>
            <float name="score">1.4317766</float>
            <str name="artist">----</str>
            <str name="artist_ex">----</str>
            <str name="book_id">bk106</str>
            <str name="id">e12683a2-faff-4d86-8107-7406491f4f89</str>
            <str name="keywords">abc</str>
            <str name="keywords_ex">abc</str>
            <str name="owner">----</str>
            <str name="owner_ex">----</str>
            <str name="title">----</str>
            <str name="title_ex">----</str>
        </doc>
        <doc>
            <float name="score">0.3288517</float>
            <str name="artist">----</str>
            <str name="artist_ex">----</str>
            <str name="book_id">bk107</str>
            <str name="id">a6a4a014-ce94-4257-a215-c1a64aa41cf5</str>
            <str name="keywords">----</str>
            <str name="keywords_ex">----</str>
            <str name="owner">----</str>
            <str name="owner_ex">----</str>
            <str name="title">abcde</str>
            <str name="title_ex">abcde</str>
        </doc>
        <doc>
            <float name="score">0.28635535</float>
            <str name="artist">----</str>
            <str name="artist_ex">----</str>
            <str name="book_id">bk104</str>
            <str name="id">9b909c65-e56a-4407-a789-53a570a7ae40</str>
            <str name="keywords">----</str>
            <str name="keywords_ex">----</str>
            <str name="owner">abc</str>
            <str name="owner_ex">abc</str>
            <str name="title">----</str>
            <str name="title_ex">----</str>
        </doc>
        <doc>
            <float name="score">0.22608554</float>
            <str name="artist">----</str>
            <str name="artist_ex">----</str>
            <str name="book_id">bk105</str>
            <str name="id">dead87cc-f93b-4562-af32-4d9fb2613c7f</str>
            <str name="keywords">abcde</str>
            <str name="keywords_ex">abcde</str>
            <str name="owner">----</str>
            <str name="owner_ex">----</str>
            <str name="title">----</str>
            <str name="title_ex">----</str>
        </doc>
        <doc>
            <float name="score">0.19090356</float>
            <str name="artist">abc</str>
            <str name="artist_ex">abc</str>
            <str name="book_id">bk103</str>
            <str name="id">306a252c-a0b5-474d-b55d-a25740d063b4</str>
            <str name="keywords">----</str>
            <str name="keywords_ex">----</str>
            <str name="owner">----</str>
            <str name="owner_ex">----</str>
            <str name="title">----</str>
            <str name="title_ex">----</str>
        </doc>
        <doc>
            <float name="score">0.020553231</float>
            <str name="artist">----</str>
            <str name="artist_ex">----</str>
            <str name="book_id">bk102</str>
            <str name="id">a684de0c-b286-4d9e-bd68-d5305afeee76</str>
            <str name="keywords">----</str>
            <str name="keywords_ex">----</str>
            <str name="owner">abcde</str>
            <str name="owner_ex">abcde</str>
            <str name="title">----</str>
            <str name="title_ex">----</str>
        </doc>
        <doc>
            <float name="score">0.008221293</float>
            <str name="artist">abcde</str>
            <str name="artist_ex">abcde</str>
            <str name="book_id">bk101</str>
            <str name="id">30a0f9de-1224-49d2-90aa-41f57af4956c</str>
            <str name="keywords">----</str>
            <str name="keywords_ex">----</str>
            <str name="owner">----</str>
            <str name="owner_ex">----</str>
            <str name="title">----</str>
            <str name="title_ex">----</str>
        </doc>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want to search across multiple fields with variable weightage, configure your request handler to use edismax query parser.
[dismax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin) allows you to search across fields and add weights to each field.

Example 
title match has weight 1, while matches on author 0.8, so that document having title matches would appear at the top.

```
<requestHandler name="search" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
   <str name="defType">edismax</str>
   <str name="qf">
      title^1 author^0.8
   </str>
   <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
   <str name="rows">10</str>
   <str name="fl">*,score</str>
 </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: I was not very complete in my description:
for each field I have a "copyField" that store the original value of related field ( with only solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory and solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory ) to allow exact match search.
Now I want to retrieve docs sorted with this logic:
1. title_exact_match
2. title
3. author_exact_match
4. view_exact_match
5. author
6. view

I try with:
select?q=abc&defType=dismax&qf=title_exact_match^1+title^0.8+author_exact_match^0.6+view_exact_match^0.4+author^0.2+view^0.1

My response isn't the one I suppose.

Comment: whats the issue with the response ? you can turn on debugQuery=on and check the response and to what contributes to the score.

Comment: I heavily edited the question to be closer to my achievement.

Comment: #1 is good. #2 - the results would make sense as the second results is a exact match on keywords as well as an edge gram so the total is 11.5, where the third result is and edge gram match for title, which is just 8 and hence lower in rank. The same would be for below results.
You would need to adjust the weights accordingly.

Comment: From where 11.5 and 8 come from?
I tried with different weights and now I'm ok...But if I change in my docs 'abcde' with 'abcdef' I fall down in the beginning problem...
I hope that '11.5' and '8' explanation will help me in this second step.

Comment: Tie seems addition (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#tie_.28Tie_breaker.29). Given one term match in each field - match on title would be factored by 8.0 and a exact and edge gram match on will be factored by 6  + 5.5 = 11 (keywords_ex^6 keywords^5.5). Try changing the tie to be max (pass tie=0 in the URL) or you need to adjust weights.

Comment: Ok, I'm reading about tie param.
But using my configuration every title_ex field will partecipate to substring match score on title field. I added *_ex fields just for exact match purpose but now they are making ranking tuning harder.
How is score calculate? How can I show the score of each field-matched per document to fine tune fields boosting? About keywords you wrote 6+5.5=11.5 but is not so simple the calculation,is just a a simplification to explain how fields match partecipate to global score, right?

Comment: yup .... its not simple as 6+5.5=11.5, hence i have mentioned given one term per field and factored score. lot of components take part in the scoring, and this may be the deciding factor given everything else is same.

Comment: So solr takes each field doc,calculates the distance between query and field value (applying its filter/tokenizer) and multiplies this score by ^field-weight and sums it to others doc fields score; at the end it has the doc's score and sort results by it.
If I start putting ^1.0 for each field I should see the "clean" score of each doc,right?